# LibGDX: Disable transparency in SpriteBatch/Sprite

Tags: libgdx, textures, sprite, spritebatch

I need to disable transparency in a Sprite or SpriteBatch. I can't find any methods to do that for a Sprite, and when I call .DisableBlending() on a SpriteBatch, and then I call .EnableBlending(), but doesn't get enabled again until it ends. 
Code outline:

```
batch.begin();

// draw non-transparent sprite.
batch.disableBlending();
batch.draw(sprite);

//draw transparent sprites
batch.enableBlending();
batch.draw(sprite2);

batch.end();
```

So what happens is sprite2 also isn't transparent. Is there any way to "update" a SpriteBatch's blending? Or, if it's impossible, disable transparency on a texture or Sprite?

Comment: You will have call begin and end of spite batch two times. Disable, begin, draw, end, enable, begin, draw, end. Does that do the trick?

Comment: @Veljko   That didn't seem to work....

Comment: After doing some testing, I found that transparency wasn't the problem at all. [solved]

Comment: Great :-) nice to hear that